# Why is iMovie 11 so unstable on my MacBook Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, imovie

On my previous MacBook Pro iMovie was slow, but stable. On this new MacBook Pro retina iMovie is fast, but extremely unstable.

- The preview window should display the correct frame when moving the
  mouse over the events. But after a while iMovie doesn't do that
  anymore, which makes finding the right piece of video very hard. A restart
  of iMovie helps in this case.
- When playing a preview, picture in picture photo's aren't displayed. The
  video freezes instead.
- When I try to export a video I often get the message that there isn't
  enough free memory. A restart of iMovie helps. But I've got 16GB's of RAM
  for crying out loud!
- The bigger a project gets, the more often iMovie completely crashes, which
  often results in lost work. :(

I tried deleting plist files. Didn't work.

I read somewhere that it could be Quicktime component files. I deleted all but the two regular component files, but that didn't help.

I read somewhere else that it could be the combination of using certain image formats and my videocard. Does that mean there is no way to fix this? And if that's the case, I'm worried upgrading to Final Cut Pro might not help.

Oh, by the way, I'm using a USB 3 external hard drive for all iMovie data (events and projects). (Nevermind, it just crashes even without the external hard drive.)

---

Here's what I get when iMovie crashes completely:

```
Process:         iMovie [1953]
Path:            /Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/MacOS/iMovie
Identifier:      com.apple.iMovieApp
Version:         9.0.8 (1778)
Build Info:      iMovieApp-1778000000000000~2
App Item ID:     408981434
App External ID: 10440451
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-12-13 20:10:41.410 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C3006)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          521160 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           40
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  51811 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   15
Anonymous UUID:                      06C1E5E8-55E0-66BD-2846-B1F8352386E6

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/MacOS/iMovie
    VM_ALLOCATE            0000000000001000-000000000008e000 [  564K] ---/--- SM=NUL  

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x92f32281 objc_assign_strongCast_non_gc + 8
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9867e37e _CFXNotificationPost + 2606
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x955fc788 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x9560c527 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 55
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x9247883c -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 136
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x924799c0 -[NSScrollView _updateTrackingAreas] + 115
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
37  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
38  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
39  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x924796b3 __42-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas]_block_invoke_0 + 33
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c8962 __NSArrayEnumerate + 594
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c84e6 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
44  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c83f5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
45  com.apple.AppKit                0x92478cb3 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1279
46  com.apple.AppKit                0x924786a2 _handleInvalidCursorRectsNote + 890
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x929ee267 __35-[NSWindow _postInvalidCursorRects]_block_invoke_02879 + 54
48  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986c228d _runLoopObserverWithBlockContext + 29
49  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98692dfe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
50  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x98692d3d __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 381
51  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9866ce16 __CFRunLoopRun + 886
52  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9866c63a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378
53  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9866c4ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
54  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950bb15a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 242
55  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950baec9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 374
56  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950bad44 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
57  com.apple.AppKit                0x923a2a3a _DPSNextEvent + 724
58  com.apple.AppKit                0x923a226c -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
59  com.apple.iMovieApp             0x000ddf3e 0x8e000 + 327486
60  com.apple.AppKit                0x923986cc -[NSApplication run] + 855
61  com.apple.AppKit                0x9233b6f6 NSApplicationMain + 1053
62  com.apple.iMovieApp             0x0009035a 0x8e000 + 9050
63  com.apple.iMovieApp             0x0008fec5 0x8e000 + 7877

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e16c02 __select_nocancel + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x99d78a08 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 376
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x99d787a9 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

Thread 2:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e16be6 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x986b0c00 __CFSocketManager + 1632
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 3:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 4:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 5:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 6:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 7:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 8:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 9:: jpegdecompress_MPLoop
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a098afc pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x9940a556 0x98cfd000 + 7394646
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b512 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef6ad TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 177
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef184 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 272
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef40d TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x992f35ac 0x98cfd000 + 6251948
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e1480e semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x997ad7ee 0x98cfd000 + 11208686
2   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x99361e26 0x98cfd000 + 6704678
3   com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 0x997ad580 0x98cfd000 + 11208064
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b512 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef6ad TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 177
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef184 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 272
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef40d TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91b907ea AIOFileThread(void*) + 892
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b512 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef6ad TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 177
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef184 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 272
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef40d TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bd51a3 TimerThread + 324
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b512 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef6ad TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 177
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef184 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 272
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef40d TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bd4ef1 DeferredTaskThread + 146
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 18:: com.apple.quicktime.VideoDecodeThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e168e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b289 _pthread_cond_wait + 938
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00b512 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef6ad TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 177
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef184 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 272
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91bef40d TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.QuickTime             0x9068ddeb VideoDecodeThread + 71
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a006557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cee thread_start + 34

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97e170ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a00904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a008e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99ff0cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x6945afe0  ebx: 0x9867d961  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x00000001  ebp: 0xbff6fbb8  esp: 0xbff6fadc
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x92f32281   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000000
Logical CPU: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried "open in low resolution" in the app's get info window?

Comment: No, good idea. I switched to Final Cut Pro X though, which doesn't have this issue.